# Idempotent relations on the unit square with closed graphs

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology

A colleague and I are interested in idempotent relations from $I=[0,1]$ to $I$ - relations such that $R\circ R(x)=R(x)$ for all $x\in I$. Specifically, the graphs of the relations we care about must be closed subsets of the square.

Is there any work in the literature addressing these objects from a topological point of view? Thanks!

Comment: Even from an algebraic standpoint, this is of interest.  If it were pure subset, this would speak of transitivity.  Equality and superset imply a form of divisibility.  I'm still considering the algebraic aspects.  Are you also interested in such relations on topological groups?  It's conceivable that there is literature on this notion for topological algebras.

Comment: Transitivity is $R \circ R \leq R$, density (or "interpolativeness"; see also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/77621/categorifying-idempotent-relations) is $R \leq R \circ R$ (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order#Generalizations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281110530_Destruction_of_metrizability_in_generalized_inverse_limits

We worked out the details to get what we needed in that paper. Specifically, if $f$ is an idempotent upper-semicontinuous continuum-valued function from $I$ to $I$ (equivalently, idempotent with a graph which is closed and connected satisfying $f(x)=[l(x),u(x)]$), then the graph of $f$ satisfies what we called condition $\Gamma$: there exists $x,y\in I$ such that $\langle x,x\rangle,\langle y,y\rangle,\langle x,y\rangle$ are all in the graph of $f$.

It would be interesting if continuum-valued was not necessary.

Edit: In https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.06827.pdf we weakened the assumptions to any weakly countably compact space, and any idempotent relation that's a closed subset of the square and yields a non-empty image and pre-image for each point.